# How can I make these images remain square when window resize?

Tags: html, css

I  have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/jka6bh1v/)

**CODE CSS:**

```css
.container{width:100%;background:yellow;height:100vh;}
    .top{
      width:100%;
      height: 60%;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      background:url("http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/BANNER-300x215.png") no-repeat center center #B03D3D;
      background-size:cover;
    }
    
    .left{
      width: 50%;
      height: 40%;
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
      background:url("http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/NEWS2-300x246.png") no-repeat center center #B03D3D;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    
    .right{
      width: 50%;
      height: 40%;
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
      right:0;
      background:url("http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/NEWS1-300x246.png") no-repeat center center #B03D3D;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>    
</div>
```

The problem is that the pictures below (the two) should always be square ... If you resize the window along and become rectangle.

Look at image below:

http://i62.tinypic.com/2nw07qe.jpg

Probably all three images must be square ... Can you tell me please how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use background-size width one dimension in `auto` and one in `100%`

https://jsfiddle.net/jka6bh1v/1/

switch respectivelly `width` with `height` if you want to fill your div

Comment: yes but the pictures should not be so small ... so I knew and they must resize

Answer (score 0):

If you want the images to be squared, you can use `padding-bottom` instead of `height`.

Remember that padding is also related to the width.

Without changing too much of your styles (probably there's better ways to approach this). 
Example:

```css
.container{width:100%;background:yellow;height:100vh;}
.top{
  width:100%;
  height: 60%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  background:url("http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/BANNER-300x215.png") no-repeat center center #B03D3D;
  background-size:cover;
}

.left{
  width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  background:url("http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/NEWS2-300x246.png") no-repeat center center #B03D3D;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.right{
  width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background:url("http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/NEWS1-300x246.png") no-repeat center center #B03D3D;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Pictures are square here now but after a certain size pass over the big picture

Answer (score 0):

```
try this when your screen resize


@media (max-width:767px) {

.container{width:100%;background:yellow;height:100vh;}
.top{
  width:100%;
  height: 60%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  background:url("http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/BANNER-300x215.png") no-repeat center center #B03D3D;
  background-size:cover;
}

.left{
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  background:url("http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/NEWS2-300x246.png") no-repeat center center #B03D3D;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.right{
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background:url("http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/NEWS1-300x246.png") no-repeat center center #B03D3D;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
}
```